# Query optimisation, NOT IN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

On the page I have an one query, which is bring page loading speed down.

```
SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users2)
```

`USERS1` is the table with all users of the site, a lot of data.
`USERS2` is the table of following eachother users.

So, I need to select some users, which is not alredy following.

Any ways of optimisation?

I'm posting real query:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users
    WHERE user_id!=156 AND user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT follower_id
        FROM following
        WHERE user_id=156
    ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
) AS temp
JOIN users ON users.user_id = temp.user_id;
```

Indexes on `user_id` fields.

Query took 0.0912 sec

This query works not bad on the testing server with less data, but it takes up to 3 seconds on live one.

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html); and ensure you have indexes on the `user_id` columns.

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` way:

```
SELECT *
FROM users1
LEFT JOIN users2 ON users1.user_id = users2.user_id
WHERE users2.user_id IS NULL
```

`NOT EXISTS` way:

```
SELECT *
FROM users1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users2 WHERE users1.user_id = users2.user_id)
```

Working examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/611f2/1

Comment: Out of curiousity: Can you cite why this is supposed to be a faster implementation of an anti-join in MySQL? In a more sophisticated database (e.g. Oracle), I wouldn't expect there to be a relevant performance difference, due to effective query transformation...

Comment: Since when MySQL is a sophisticated database? :) These queries may or may not be faster. OP is encouraged to use/interpret the `EXPLAIN` command.

Comment: @LukasEder: Agreed.  [Quassnoi's analysis](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) reaches the same conclusion.

Comment: @eggyal: That seems to be a good resource... Yet it's crazy to have to do that kind of fine-tuning manually. I'm glad I live in Oracle-land... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` for best performance as:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM users1 a
     LEFT JOIN users2 b
        ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL;
```

Also have a look at [Visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Out of curiousity: Can you cite why this is supposed to be a faster implementation of an anti-join in MySQL? In a more sophisticated database (e.g. Oracle), I wouldn't expect there to be a relevant performance difference, due to effective query transformation...

Comment: @LukasEder: Agreed.  [Quassnoi's analysis](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) reaches the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT users1.* FROM users1
LEFT JOIN users2 on users1.user_id=users2.user_id
WHERE users2.user_id IS NULL
```